# Why does getting a firestore collection work correctly in a vuex action, but the updated data is not passed to the getter?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuejs3

I have a collection of products stored in Firestore, each of which has a subcollection of product prices (the documents of this collection are generated through the Stripe for Firebase plugin, as an aside).

I am attempting to retrieve this list of products through a Vuex action, like so:

```js
export default createStore({
  state: {
    productList: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    setProductList(state, value) {
      state.productList = value;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async retrieveProducts({ commit }) {
      let productList = []; //init empty list
      //query all active products
      const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q); //get product documents
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        // for each document, map data in a useful way to productList
        let product = doc.data();
        product.id = doc.id;

        product.priceList = []; // init empty pricelist

        const priceSnap = collection(db, "products/", doc.id, "/prices"); //prepare to get all documents in the price subcollection

        let priceDocs = await getDocs(priceSnap); // retrieve the pricelist
        priceDocs.forEach((doc) => {
          // format each document's data
          let price = doc.data();
          price.id = doc.id;
          // add price data to product PriceList
          product.priceList.push(price);
        });

        productList.push(product);
        // add finished product object to product List
      });
      commit("setProductList", productList); // send productList to requester
      console.log("Product List: ", productList); //verify productList integrity
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getProductList(state) {
      return state.productList;
    },
  },
});
```

When the action is run, the final console.log shows the correctly formatted `productList` variable. However, on the Vue side, where this request takes place, it returns with an empty Array.

The request looks like this:

```js
 async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch({
      type: "retrieveProducts",
    });
    
    this.pList = this.$store.getters.getProductList;
    console.log("pList length: ", this.pList.length)
    console.log("Pricing.Vue: ",this.pList)
    if (this.pList.length > 0) {
      console.log("great success");
    } else {
      console.log("error loading product list.");
    }
  }
```

The especially confusing part is that if I omit the second getDocs and not query the sub-collection, this code functions correctly.

I'm at a total loss for what is not working correctly here.